# VideoView loses back stack

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have to refactor some old code and am currently up against a wall. Apparently this code used to load a different kind of video format but now it pulls in an .MP4, which means the WebView it used to call can no longer play the video. Given the extremely finite amount of time I have, I tried to kludge in a VideoView to play the video. The video loads and plays, but the activity stack is lost when the VideoView is started.

I have overwritten the MediaController class to at least be able to capture the back key event. My question is: how can I load this VideoView and retain the activity stack?

I appreciate your time and patience.

Here is the code calling the VideoView:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Video video =  (Video) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    track("Video", "VOD", video.title);
    String url = video.link.substring(29);
    if(DEBUG_MODE)
        Log.d("TDF", url);
    url = Kriptonic.getEncryptedURL(url);

    videoView = new VideoView(_myActivity);
    _myActivity.setContentView(videoView);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    mc = new CustomMediaController(_myActivity);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();

}
```

EDIT:

I solved this by not being lazy. Just creating a video like that without attaching it to its own activity was just bad coding. I created a simple activity, started an intent in the above fragment to call that activity and all is fine.

...For everything but ICS. It won't run in ICS. But that will be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Cache the previous view in a temporary variable and restore the contentView to it when back is pressed.

```
mainView = _myActivity.getContentView();
videoView = new VideoView(_myActivity);
_myActivity.setContentView(videoView);
```

When back button is pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mainView != null) {
        _myActivity.setContentView(mainView);
        mainView = null;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```